# Using Apache Shiro SecurityUtils in a Filter

Tags: spring-boot, servlet-filters, shiro

I'm using a Filter in a Spring Boot web application to log all my user requests to a database. One of the things I'd like to log is the username, but when I try to get the current user using:

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal()
```

I get the following error:

```
No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton. This is an invalid application configuration.
```

What do I need to do so that my Filter is able to retrieve the current user?

Comment: You sure that shiro environment started successfully? please share your shiro.ini file

Answer (score 2):

You need to have at least one url defined for your filter mapping:
https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/1.4.x/samples/spring-boot-web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/examples/WebApp.java#L96-L101

And of course the Shiro servlet filter configured (which I'm guessing you already have)

Take a look at the above example.

Comment: I have a configuration bean that returns an AbstractShiroFilter, with URLs configured. However, the filter that I'm using to record the users is not a ShiroFilter. Does it need to be? I thought I could access the SecurityUtils anywhere within my application?

Comment: Just put the Shiro filter in front of our own filter, and you should be all set.

Comment: What do you mean by put the Shiro filter in front of my filter? Do you mean the Shiro filter must be executed before my filter, or do you mean I need to wrap my filter in Shiro? If it's the former, how do I change the ordering of the Shiro filter?

Comment: The Shiro filter needs to execute before yours in the filter chain.  You should be able to use `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean.setOrder()` to configure the order of your filter

Comment: I've set the order on my Filter to be as large as it can be (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`), yet it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is the code public anywhere?  (can you provide a reproduce case?)